# Dotfuscator - does obfuscate .msi file?

Tags: installation, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I've a .Net solution with .msi output. Running obfuscation (using `Dotfuscate`) throws following error:

```
PE Signature not found.  Is \Release\Output.msi a PE file?
```

Wondering if `Dotfuscate` doesn't support .`msi` file obfuscation.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dotfuscator does not obfuscate `.msi` files, only .NET assemblies (`.dll` and `.exe` files made with C#, F#, or Visual Basic .NET). If you are shipping .NET assemblies in an `.msi`, you will need to use Dotfuscator to protect them before they are added to your `.msi`.

The easiest way to do this is to [integrate Dotfuscator into your app's `.exe` project](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html). Then, when you build the project in Visual Studio or MSBuild, Dotfuscator will protect the assemblies in `bin\Release` (both the `.exe` from the integrated project as well as `.dll`s from other projects in your solution), which your `.msi` can then pick up as normal. This also allows Dotfuscator to work with other packaged formats, like Xamarin, as this integration runs after the project is compiled but before it is packaged.

(*Disclaimer*: I work for the Dotfuscator team and am answering as part of my job.)

Comment: "Dotfuscator will protect the assemblies in bin\Release [...] which your .msi can then pick up as normal" only that that's not what normally gets picked up. The Windows Installer Project extension for Visual Studio gets the 'Primary Output' of a project, which, for an .exe,  includes the dlls from bin\Release, but the .exe from \obj\Release. Which is not obfuscated. And then the installed unobfuscated executable will crash on startup because it cannot find its dependencies in the installed obfuscated dlls.